# Is it good to route PCB tracks under a heatsink?

Tags: pcb-design

A heat sink is a piece of metal. If the solder mask on a PCB track is broken, it may be dangerous, right?

Below is a small heatsink for TO220, seen from bottom.

[image]

Comment: Why would the solder mask get damaged? Especially if it is under a heat sink?

Comment: What is the insulation withstand voltage of solder mask?

Comment: @Dean : abrasion under severe vibration, in a harsh environment.

Comment: If you intend to have it evaluated for use in the industrial environment solder mask is not considered insulating. It scratches so easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A heat sink is a piece of metal. If the solder mask on a PCB track is
>   broken, it may be dangerous, right?

If in doubt, use an insulating spacer: -

[image]

For heatsinks like these: -

[image]

I use small fibre washers like these over the solderable legs: -

[image]

Comment: There are some heatsinks installed vertically with legs, such as the small heatsinks for TO220. It seems they are installed directly on the PCB. In the worst case, they may scratch the solder mask.

Comment: In these situations I put thin fibre washers over the solderable legs to space the heatsink by ~1mm

Answer (score 1):

> A heat sink is a piece of metal.

While a heat sink is a piece of metal, it will affect the impedances of the traces below it, for ground and power traces, this won't be a problem. But for signal traces the changed impedance may affect the outcome signal quality.

Outside the fact that signals are affected, mounting the heatsink directly on the PCB can cause increased wear on the PCB if the heatsink expands and contracts with a different rate than the PCB itself due to heating. This problem can be migrated by using spacers.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your heat sink a little spacing from the PCB. In that case it cannot scratch your solder mask.

If it is directly on the PCB I would route the traces on the other side of the PCB or around the footprint of the heatsink.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay route PCB tracks under a heatsink. Even if the heatsink is connected to VCC and the route is ground. For 2 reasons: 1, soldering mask are very hard to scratch off. I need to use a very sharp blade to go through the surface 3 times to reveal the copper, a very sharp blade; so it's very unlikely that your heatsink will do any damage to the mask; 2, heatsinks are not supposed to move around, so it is safe even under a ground route.